# Haml: Conditional with list items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I've got the following block:

```
#control-panel
  %h3
    = "Manage"
  %ul.left-panel
    %li{:class => 'my-profile'}
      = link_to 'Profile', edit_user_path(current_user)
    %li{:class => 'my-account'}
      = link_to 'Account', edit_account_user_path(current_user)
  -if @user && current_user.parent?
    %li{:class => 'my-blog'}
      = link_to 'Blog', manage_user_posts_path(current_user)
```

The problem is the if conditional on that last list item...doing it like that renders a closed `</ul>` tag and then another list item. What I need is for that last list item to be a part of the unordered list if it meets the conditional.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indent the -if and subsequent %li so they are in the same column as the %li elements above.

```
%ul.left-panel
  %li{:class => 'my-profile'}
    = link_to 'Profile', edit_user_path(current_user)
  %li{:class => 'my-account'}
    = link_to 'Account', edit_account_user_path(current_user)
  -if @user && current_user.parent?
    %li{:class => 'my-blog'}
      = link_to 'Blog', manage_user_posts_path(current_user)
```

Also, just looking at your code, I'm guessing that the visitor is already a @user, if they can access the Profile and Account links, so the if @user may be redundant?